# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." when trying to access list view as admin. Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have this simple view I built using Django REST framework:

```
class ProductListCreateAPIView(
        StaffEditorPermissionMixin,
        generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(serializer.validated_data)
        name = serializer.validated_data.get('name')
        description = serializer.validated_data.get('description') or None
        if description is None:
            description = name
        serializer.save(description=description)
```

here is the StaffEditorPermissionMixin:

```
class StaffEditorPermissionMixin():
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser, IsStaffEditorPermission]
```

and here is the ProductSerializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    edit_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='product-details',
        lookup_field='pk',
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'url',
            'edit_url',
            'name',
            'description',
            'price',
            'sale_price',
        ]

    def get_edit_url(self, obj):
        # return f"/api/v2/products/{obj.pk}/"
        request = self.context.get('request')

        if request is None:
            return None
        return reverse("product-edit", kwargs={"pk": obj.pk}, request=request)
```

and just in case here's products.url:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='product-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', views.ProductUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='product-edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.ProductDestroyAPIView.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/',  views.ProductDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='product-details'),
]
```

and just in case here's the source urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('api/products/', include('product.urls')),
    path('api/v2/', include('rest_practice.routers')),
]
```

so when I am logging in as admin to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ and I head to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/ I cannot access the product list and receiving

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

So I don't know why authentication is not working so any help would be appreciated

EDIT: I am using Django's own admin panel

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is a little bit unclear on whether you mean Django's own admin panel or you have one of your own that calls that endpoint. This is happening because while going to that page from the admin, the request doesn't include your user's token.

That being said, I think its better to disassociate the ListCreateAPIView from the admin pages (if you're talking about Django's own admin pages), so that the view would be the logic serving the API calls. To  do that, all you have to modify is the admin.py file within your app folder to be something like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['some_column',...]
    list_display = [...]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and yes I am using Django's own admin panel but is there a reason why my request is not including my user's token? considering I am fairly new to all of this and I am following along a tutorial he has done it with no problem and without modifying admin.py

Comment: It's a bit uncommon to use a View for the admin pages, since Django has its own admin panel. to be able to go to the products page on the admin panel, the URL would not be http://127.0.0.1:8000/APP_NAME/MODEL_NAME and you don't need to write the url yourself as you just can access the product model from the admin page itself after implementing the admin model registration above.

Answer (score 1):

I have forgotten to change DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION CLASSES where I had it set up like this

```
auth_classes = [
    "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    "api.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
]

if DEBUG:
    auth_classes = ["api.authentication.TokenAuthentication"]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": auth_classes,
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly",
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser",  # ONLY GET METHODS
    ],
}
```

where it should be something like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "api.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly",
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser",  # ONLY GET METHODS
    ],
}
```